# Updating a WCF address in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core web app. One of its functions will need to use normal .NET, so I've created a WCF service for this and connected it to the app.

This works, but how do I update the address of the service reference once my app and service are deployed on another machine? This will be a PROD machine so I won't have Visual Studio and Add Connected Service.

For example, in the published folder for the web app there is a Connected Services\MyService\ConnectedService.json file which has the service address in it, but changing this address makes no difference to what the web app wants to call, despite restarting IIS.

Examples online show how to create the service manually, e.g.:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost/MyService/MyService.svc"));
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<MyService.IServiceChannel>(binding, endpoint);
var serviceClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
await serviceClient.DoSomething(1, 2, 3);
channelFactory.Close();
```

However when I do this and pass in the IIS service address it doesn't work, and I get a response saying:

```
The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding...
```

What I'm really hoping is that there can might be a simple config text file, maybe within appsettings.json, with 'endPointAddress' or something similar. I could create this manually, but how then do I use that to correctly connect to the service?

In short my question is: how do you change the address of a WCF endpoint without going through the Add Connected Service helper?

Comment: The content type text/html = The horrible yellow exception in html of what went wrong server side being sent back over the wire, however, the client was expecting the xml/json/soap response. You either need to catch exceptions in your service and return an xml/json/soap response with a http status code and a custom message such as  "oops something went wrong..."+exception.ToString(). If you view the html contents of the payload, it probably has  details of the problem encoded inside the html.

Comment: Thanks. Why would the service on IIS expect something different from the debug service?

Comment: You have service1 configured to receive json over the wire then service1 calls service2 to return the json data. However, your endpoint bindings for service1 specify an incorrect url for service2, in which case the default behavior is for the IIS instance running service2 is to return a 404 response in html format, as it has no idea as to the clients preferred format (...unless you override that behavior in service2). In this scenario service1 is receiving HTML but expects something else. This likely means your endpoint configuration is off by a bit.

Comment: Can you post the html message?

Comment: Thanks for your help Ross. After trying to get the full HTML I ran into more problems, and in researching those I found that I did not have the Role/Feature "HTTP Activation" enabled for WCF. After activating that, it started working normally and I can change the end point without issue. Thanks again.